# Master theorem $T(n)=2T(n/4)+ \sqrt{n}+\log^2(n)$

Tags: algorithms

How to know if master theorem applies here: $T(n)=2T(n/4)+ \sqrt{n}+\log^2(n)$.

I don't know how to take $f(n) = \sqrt{n} + \log^2(n)$ because it seems that is not included in none of the three cases.

Can someone please explain me the logic of this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

The point of this recurrence is finding a $n^k$ upper bound of $f(n)$.

In this case, you can apply

> Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$ such that $a >0$, $b > 1$, $c > 0$. Then, $$(\log_b n)^a \subset \mathcal O(n^c)$$

so 
$$f(n) = \sqrt{n} + \log^2(n) \subset \mathcal O(\sqrt{n}) = \mathcal O(n^{0.5})$$

You can also prove that $\log^2 (n) \subset \mathcal O(\sqrt{n})$ by taking limits and using L'Hôpital's Rule.

Finally, as long as $$T(n) = 2\;T(n/4) + \mathcal O(n^{0.5})$$
you're ready to apply Master theorem.

Comment: so, the answer for the problem after I applied Master theorem is: T(n) = O($n^\frac{1}{2}$log(n)) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Indeed, it is $T(n) = \Theta(\sqrt{n}\log n)$.